# how to format the ffmpeg command to record sound from my webcam

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone, soundcard, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg arecord -L, I am able to identify my Logitech usb webcam as:

```
hw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0
USB Device 0x46d:0x821, USB Audio
Direct hardware device without any conversions

plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0
USB Device 0x46d:0x821, USB Audio
Hardware device with all software conversions
```

when I go into /dev/snd/by-id, the webcam is described as:

```
usb-046d_0821_6813BFD0-00 -> ../controlC1
```

I know that the command to use a sound device in ffmpeg is

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i $ALSA_DEVICE_NAME..
```

I have tried

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i "hw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0" and

ffmpeg -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0"
```

and in both cases I receive the same error message

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2208:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw=CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0
[alsa @ 0x9c96580] cannot open audio device hw=CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0 (No such file or directory)
hw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0: Input/output error
```

I have also tried

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i "usb-046d_0821_6813BFD0-00" and

ffmpeg -f alsa -i "usb-046d_0821_6813BFD0-00,DEV=0" and have still received error message
```

Could use some help in formulating the correct format of the command

Answer (score 6):

The following is the correct way:

1. Issue the `arecord -L` command.
2. Look for the `plughw` values which corresponds to your hardware. Please note that plughw represents a hardware which has been plugged into the computer.
3. Crosscheck the values in `/dev/snd/by-id` directory.

   - When you unplug the webcam(s), the `by-id` sub directory will vanish from the `/dev/snd` directory. This is an excellent test to confirm which `plughw` is an externally plugged in device.
4. The sound device(s) ID listed there will be the same as or correspond to one of the values obtained from the `arecord -L` command.
5. The command to use is `ffmpeg: -f alsa -i plughw`.
6. Please note, do NOT enclose the plughw value in quotes.
7. A working example for me was:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x821,DEV=0 -acodec libmp3lame -t 20 output.mp4
   ```
8. You may add the video portion to the above command by adding:

   ```
   -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0
   ```

I hope this helps. Any related question(s) is/are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick read of the man page for ffmpeg and they recommend looking in /proc/asound/cards

I have two cards on my machine 0 and 1 and my web cam is 1 so the command for me is

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try it and it didn't work. I however retried <b> arecord -L </b> and used the <b>plughw:....</b> value, this time without enclosing the value in quotes and that did work